# Visual studio regex to match swallowed exceptions

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I need a Visual Studio regex to match swallowed exceptions.

This is as far as I got, but it still matches valid code like this:

```
catch (ArgumentNullException)
{
  //...
  throw;
}


catch:Wh*\(:Wh*.*Exception.*\):Wh*\{[:Wh*.*]*[^(throw:Wh*.*;)].*
```

How can I fix this?

Edit: Am I to take it from the comments that testing for the absence of a pattern in a regular expression in Visual Studio is not possible? - This is the thrust of my question.  I would like to put aside questions of validity of approach (I am fully aware of FxCop et al, lexing and parsing, and this [seminal post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454). I am also aware that swallowing exceptions is sometimes OK).

Comment: I've seen some pretty bad instances of using regexes for completely inappropriate tasks before, but this really takes the cake.

Comment: You can't reliably parse C++ with regexps. I don't know VS but would be surprised if there wasn't some tool or plug-in to help you. Sure, swallowed exceptions are bad, except when they aren't. At some point you'll have to code-review them and the best you can hope for is a tool that gives false positives for you to examine and document.

Comment: @Anon, please can you expand upon why this is inappropriate. There may be false positives. It may not be possible to find all swallowed exceptions, but as a tool for identifying areas to review, it surely could be useful?

Comment: @Anon: There's always the regex that identifies non-prime numbers, which already has the cake and will not let go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here. This is an academic question, because, or course, there is a fundamental difference in the capabilities of a context free grammar and a regular expression as previous commenters have so eagerly pointed out, plus there are manifold existing non-regex -based tools that will perform this functionality for me.

I wanted to explore the negative lookahead capabilities of Visual Studio. According to reports in the comments [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/the-visual-studio-ide-and-regular-expressions.html) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vseditor/thread/d0f4df02-6dde-4971-b614-b43e53351bad), the negative lookahead behavior of Visual Studio does not behave as you might expect under some circumstances (to the point of some calling it buggy).

I am not an expert on regular expressions, but i would expect the regex `(throw)` to match a line containing only `throw` - and indeed it does. I would also expect `~(throw)` (this is the syntax for the negative lookahead in Visual Studio) *not* to match that same line - but, in Visual Studio, it *does*.

Having toyed with refining my original regular expression, including simplifying the test pattern, I come to the conclusion that performing negative lookaheads using the current implementation of Visual Studio's regular expression search is difficult, nigh impossible.